# Variable Cell Reference in VLOOKUP lookup_value

Tags: variables, reference, cell, vlookup

My question is very simple, but I cannot come to the answer for a long time.

In my first sheet I have such data:

[image: Sheet1]

My second sheet has VLOOKUP function, the table looks like this:

[image: Sheet2]

What I want to do is to VLOOKUP read the value of field B1 on sheet2 and to put that value as plain number in lookup_value part of the function.

So when I type in  B3 (sheet2) number 3, function should automaticly change value as next:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3;Sheet1!A1:B6;2;FALSE)
```

When I type number 6, it should change to:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A6;Sheet1!A1:B6;2;FALSE)
```

and bring the value from that row.

Literally B2 on sheet2 should play role of row# of cell in sheet1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an aswer, I needed to call INDIRECT function.

So function should be:

=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&B1);Sheet1!A1:B6;2;FALSE)

Maybe it will help somebody.

BR
Milos :)